# Get all checkboxes worked

Tags: c#, loops, checkedlistbox

I have something like this:

```
if (form.checkBox1.Checked)
     sel.SetElementIds(wallID);

if (form.checkBox2.Checked)
     sel.SetElementIds(columnID);

if (form.checkBox3.Checked)
     sel.SetElementIds(beamID);
```

Basically, I have 3 checkboxes. There are 3 actions accordingly. When I check only 1 box, it works perfectly individually.The problem is, when I check 2 or 3 boxes, only the last action works (not all of them). I tried again with a foreach loop:

```
foreach (Object a in form.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    if ((string)a == "Wall")
    {
        sel.SetElementIds(wallID);
    }

    if ((string)a == "Column")
    {
        sel.SetElementIds(columnID);
    }

    if ((string)a == "Beam")
    {
        sel.SetElementIds(beamID);
    }
}
```

It produces the same result. I cannot get all 3 actions altogether.

Ideally, I want to get multiple actions at the same time when I check multiple boxes.

Any ideas will be so appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you debug the code?

Comment: The code you've posted is not a [mcve] (it's incomplete). First try stepping through the code in the debugger to see if you can figure out what's going wrong. If that doesn't work, [edit] your question to include a complete example of your code that can be copied, pasted, compiled and executed that demonstrates the issue.